# Django HttpResponseRedirect versus redirect

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse

Given the following:

```
def add(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        task = request.POST.get('task')        
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]            
            request.session['tasks'] += [task]           
        
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tasks:index"))
            return redirect('tasks:index')
        
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
                "form": form
            })
    return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
        "form": NewTaskForm()
    })
```

what's the difference, why would you use one over the other, between:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tasks:index"))
```

and:

```
return redirect('tasks:index')
```

Comment: The two are equivalent. The `redirect` is defined in the `shortcuts` module to make it shorter. It also has a more convenient parameter interface.

Comment: ```return redirect('tasks:index')``` why we use colon in betweem tasks and index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`redirect(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/shortcuts.py#L23-L41):

> ```
> def redirect(to, *args, permanent=False, **kwargs):
>     redirect_class = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect if permanent else HttpResponseRedirect
>     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
> ```

where `resolve_url` is a layer around the [**`reverse(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/shortcuts.py#L102-L141):

> ```
> def resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Return a URL appropriate for the arguments passed.
>     The arguments could be:
>         * A model: the model's `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.
>         * A view name, possibly with arguments: `urls.reverse()` will be used
>           to reverse-resolve the name.
>         * A URL, which will be returned as-is.
>     """
>     # If it's a model, use get_absolute_url()
>     if hasattr(to, 'get_absolute_url'):
>         return to.get_absolute_url()
>
>     if isinstance(to, Promise):
>         # Expand the lazy instance, as it can cause issues when it is passed
>         # further to some Python functions like urlparse.
>         to = str(to)
>
>     if isinstance(to, str):
>         # Handle relative URLs
>         if to.startswith(('./', '../')):
>             return to
>
>     # Next try a reverse URL resolution.
>     try:
>         return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
>     except NoReverseMatch:
>         # If this is a callable, re-raise.
>         if callable(to):
>             raise
>         # If this doesn't "feel" like a URL, re-raise.
>         if '/' not in to and '.' not in to:
>             raise
>
>     # Finally, fall back and assume it's a URL
>     return to
> ```

It is thus a more "rich" way to resolve URL's since:

1. if the object has a [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) it will return the result of this method;
2. if is a `Promise`, it will *evaluate* the promise;
3. if it is a *relative URL*, it will return the URL; and
4. if the `reverse(…)` *fails* and it looks like a URL, it will return the value you passed itself, since then it assumes it is an (absolute) URL.

It thus does not only aim to find a view with that name, but does some extra things.

Furthermore the way you use parameters is more convenient with redirect. If the url looks like:

```
app_name = 'tasks'

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('page/<slug:myslug>/', some_view, name='page')
]
```

then when you use `reverse(…)`, you provide a value for the `myslug` parameter with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks:index', args=('value',)))
```

or:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks:index', kwargs={'myslug': 'value'}))
```

whereas with a redirect, you can use:

```
return redirect('tasks:index', 'value')
```

or:

```
return redirect('tasks:index', myslug='value')
```

Comment: ```return redirect('tasks:index')```  why we use colon in betweem tasks and index?

Comment: @TariqAhmed: the `tasks` is the namespace, and you specify a viewname, if you use namespaces, with `namespace:viewname`.

Comment: I didn't understand.. it should be ```<slug:any_name>```  I see this ```namespace:viewname``` first time..

Comment: @TariqAhmed: that's for a URL parameter: here we do the opposite: we calculate a URL from a view name. If namespaced URLs are used (if the `urs.py` for example contains an `app_name`), then that has to be prefixed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#introduction

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, in terms of functionality, in terms of readability, yes!

HttpResponseRedirect comes from django.http library and redirect() comes from django.shortcuts library.

It's the same like using the either the render() [comes from django.shortcuts] function or TemplateResponse() [comes from django.templates]